# Why wont my code return a value for the data input into a tkinter text box

Tags: python, tkinter

I have written this code and for some reason it refuses to return any sort of value or input for slef.REV when used in the function post(self) however it will return a value when I try and return a value in the getlen() function which is used to reurn the number of characters in the review.I dont have this problem for any other variables that I retrieve data from within this class. Below is the relevant code, any help would be appreciated. the lines where this problem occures is the first functio calld post(lines 1-5) and 4 lines up from the bottom

```
def post(self):
        MovieID = self.MovID
        REV = self.REV
        AddReview(conn,cursor,Add_Review,MovieID,REV)
        print(REV) 


def shrek_film(self):


    self.title = "Shrek" 
    self.MovID = 1
    self.root4 = tk.Toplevel()
    self.root4.title("Watch Shreck")
    self.root4.geometry("1400x800")
    frame_4 = tk.Frame(self.root4, bg = "black")
    frame_4.pack(fill = tk.BOTH, expand = True, padx=0 , pady=0)
    frame_4.grid_columnconfigure(1,weight=1)

    self.Create_canvas = tk.Canvas(frame_4, width=2000, height=1080)
    self.Create_canvas.place(x=-50, y=-50)
    self.Create_img = PhotoImage(file="shrek-landscape.gif")
    self.Create_canvas.create_image(20, 20, anchor = NW, image=self.Create_img)

    play_button= tk.Button(frame_4,bg="orange",text="play", command = self.addHistory)
    play_button.place(x=700,y=400)
    play_button.config(font=("Ariel","30"))


    def gtelen():
        Review = reviewbox.get('1.0',END)
        REVLEN = len(Review)
        REVLENLEFT = (231-len(Review))
        if REVLEN >=230:
            lenbox = tk.Label(frame_4 ,text="No words left",bg="orange")
            lenbox.place(x=360,y=460)
            lenbox.config(font=("Ariel","15"))
        else:
            lenbox = tk.Label(frame_4 ,text=REVLENLEFT,bg="orange")
            lenbox.place(x=360,y=460)
            lenbox.config(font=("Ariel","15"))
            print(Review)



    Words_button = tk.Button(frame_4, bg="orange",text="check number of words remaining", command=gtelen)
    Words_button.place(x=150,y=460)
    Words_button.config(font=("Ariel","10"))

    reviewlable=tk.Label(frame_4,text="Write a review",bg="orange")
    reviewlable.place(x=10,y=460)
    reviewlable.config(font=("ariel","15"))

    Review_button= tk.Button(frame_4,bg="orange",text="See Reviews")#, command = self.ViewReviews)
    Review_button.place(x=490,y=450)
    Review_button.config(font=("Ariel","15"))

    reviewbox= Text(frame_4,width=100,height=12)
    reviewbox.place(x=10,y=500)
    self.REV = reviewbox.get('1.0',END)

    post_button = tk.Button(frame_4,bg="orange",text="Post Review", command = self.post)
    post_button.place(x=830,y=650)
    post_button.config(font=("Ariel","15"))
```

Comment: It seems that the code you shared has some formatting issues. Please correct the code so it will be easier for everyone to help you and understand the issue. Also, please refer to the line(s) of code that you are having problem with.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Entry instead and use a StringVar

```
v = StringVar()                                                         # Create StringVar
reviewbox = Entry(frame_4, width = 100, height = 12, textvariable = v)  # Create Entry widget
reviewbox.place(x = 10, y = 500)                                        # Place Entry widget
self.REV = v.get()                                                      # Get contents of StringVar
```

Comment: This will have exactly the same behavior as the OP's code.

Answer (score -1):

The line `self.REV = reviewbox.get('1.0',END)` is being called about a millisecond after creating the text widget. The user will not even have seen the widget yet, much less have had time to type in it.

You can't call the `get()` method until after the user has had a chance to enter data, such as inside the `post` method.

```
def post(self):
    MovieID = self.MovID
    REV = reviewbox.get("1.0", "end")
    AddReview(conn,cursor,Add_Review,MovieID,REV)
    print(REV)
```